# Can I wrap an external library to avoid conflicts?

Tags: c++, gcc, static-libraries

I am working on a large project that uses opencv2.x  I want to use opencv 3.0 for one particular feature.  Upgrading to the 3.0 will break my current project.  I was hoping to create my own static library wrapper that encapsulates opencv3.0 in it's own namespace.  Is it possible to create mylib.a that encapsulates opencv3.0 so I link against mylib.a in my main project without having to link against any of the opencv3.0 libs in my main project?

Comment: I assume you are using gcc?

Comment: You will have then  a program with both OpenCV libraries loaded at runtime, but yes you can if you have the patience ;)

Comment: @rlam I have the patience :)  I am receiving linking errors in my main program, when trying to link mylib.a.  It is looking for opencv libs.  I statically linked them when building mylib.a ... Is there something I need to do outside just statically link the opencv libs?